# Color-fill an area inside a border with Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing

I have an image that is all black with a shape's edges outlined in white. I also have the center coordinates for the feature being outlined. Is there a function I can use to fill in that area?

[image: Outline Image]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is pretty simple

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFsL7.png"];
FillingTransform[img]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Further details

[image]

> What about the center coordinates? Could the outline be anywhere inside the black image? – Peter Mortensen

If you use `FillingTransform`, the object can be located anywhere inside the image, but if you understand the basics, it is easy to write a simple solution yourself. First, what you have is a black and white image where white pixels represent the contour you want to fill. If this contour is closed, all you have to do is to find a point inside the object and fill all black pixels until you meet the white boundary.

For reasonably convex objects, the `Centroid` is a good place to start as a pixel inside the object. Note that `FillingTransform` does it differently and works in more general ways:

> An extended minimum is a connected set of pixels surrounded by pixels that all have a greater value than the pixels in the set. `FillingTransform[image]` fills all extended minima by lifting their values to the lowest value found among the surrounding pixels.

For your simple situation, we can use a flood-fill starting from an inside pixel that stops when it reaches an already filled pixel. Let's first find the centroid of your fish object:

```
ComponentMeasurements[img, "Centroid"]
(* {1 -> {668.156, 391.217}, 2 -> {846., 473.}} *)
```

The second object is a small white dot inside your fish. We ignore that. The algorithm works as follow: It uses a start position. If the start position is a black pixel, it fills the pixel with white and looks then on all neighbors. What happens is that all pixels we want to fill are pushed on a stack, and then the stack is processed until it is empty.

Therefore, here a crude version a simple stack:

```
Module[{$s},
 stack[elm_] := ($s = {elm});
 push[elm_] := ($s = {elm, $s});
 top[] := If[empty[], $Failed, First[$s]];
 pop[] := If[empty[], $Failed,
   With[{top = top[]},
    $s = If[Length[$s] > 1, Last[$s], {}];
    top
    ]
   ];
 empty[] := TrueQ[Length[$s] < 1]
]
```

If you don't understand why I am using a `Module` variable `$s` here, please read [this post from Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/187).

The flood-fill itself is now simple. If you want details on the algorithm, you can read through the [queue implementation on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations). This one is similar. The only things to mention are:

1. I'm checking if the initial point lies indeed inside the image
2. I'm padding the image with a one-pixel layer of white. With this, the algorithm will always terminate at the image boundary. When returning the result, I'm removing this padding again.
3. I need to *reverse* the image matrix because image coordinates and matrix coordinates have a different y-direction.

Here is the implementation

```
floodFill[img_Image, init : {_Integer, _Integer}] :=
 Module[{result = img, nx, ny, data, x, y},
  If[Not[1 <= init[[1]] <= nx && 1 <= init[[2]] <= ny],
   Return[result]
   ];
  stack[init + {1, 1}];
  data = ArrayPad[Reverse@ImageData[img, "Bit"], 1, 1];
  While[Not[empty[]],
   {x, y} = pop[];
   If[data[[y, x]] == 0,
    data[[y, x]] = 1;
    push[{x, y + 1}];
    push[{x, y - 1}];
    push[{x + 1, y}];
    push[{x - 1, y}];
    ]
   ];
  Image[Reverse@ArrayPad[data, -1]]
  ]
```

And now you can call `floodFill[img, {668, 391}]` to get your result.

Comment: What about the center coordinates? Could the outline be anywhere inside the black image?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have given more details in my answer. Please see the edits.